# Android/ Google Map - simulate Google Map device location focus

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm looking for help with my Android app.

In Google map, when you click on the MyLocationButton, the camera will lock onto the device's movement until the map is dragged away. I'm trying to simulate this behavior in my map.

My current code is able to return the device's location and lock onto it. The problem is with updating locking/unlocking state.

The idea i had was:
 - on default, camera lock onto device.
 - when camera move, check the position when it stopped. IF it stopped on top of device location then camera is still locked. ELSE camera is unlocked.

Is this the right approach or are there better ways?

Thanks,
code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map loaded");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Eat Safe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    map = googleMap;

    if (locationPermissionGranted) {
        getLastKnownLocation();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onMyLocationButtonClick: camera locked");
                cameraLocked = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
        map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                Log.d(TAG, "setOnCameraIdleListener: camera Idle");
                LatLng cameraPosition = map.getCameraPosition().target;
                if(cameraPosition.equals(myLocation)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "setOnCameraIdleListener: camera on top of device");

                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "setOnCameraIdleListener: camera unlocked");
                    cameraLocked = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I worked it out.

I changed setOnCameraIdleListener to onCameraMove which made more sense.

This way, each time camera moved, check to see if camera is on top of device or not.

then, the onCameraMove inside needs to account for some errors as they passes back decimals values.